# Mysql 5.1 on Mac: query cache not working

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I have set up a local Mysql 5.1 sandbox on my Snow Leopard OSX machine, I have the Macports Mysql 5.1 installed and, by all appearances, functioning.  It takes queries, the database is working, etc.  The only strange thing is, the query cache isn't functioning. I have gotten it functioning in linux before, and gotten it working in a 5.0 xammp install, but I am flummoxed as to why it isn't working in this set up.

Some details...

```
% cat /etc/my.cnf | grep -i query_cache
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 32M
query_cache_type = 1

mysql> show variables like '%query_cache%';
+------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                | Value    |
+------------------------------+----------+
| have_query_cache             | YES      |
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576  |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096     |
| query_cache_size             | 33554432 |
| query_cache_type             | ON       |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF      |
+------------------------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status like '%Qcache%';
+-------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name           | Value    |
+-------------------------+----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 1        |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 33536856 |
| Qcache_hits             | 0        |
| Qcache_inserts          | 0        |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0        |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 433      |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 0        |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 1        |
+-------------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

It looks to me like everything is set up correctly, these are basically the same settings I have used on 5.0 and 4.1.  The most of the queries are cache-able, and I am not excluding the cache specifically.  I don't know if it a Mac issue, a MacPorts problem, or a 5.1 problem, or my personal problem. Can anyone see anything wrong with my setup?

---

Ok, some additional information.  This seems to be related to Innodb. MyISAM queries seem to cache just fine.

My inno setup:

```
$ cat /etc/my.cnf | grep nno

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_data_home_dir = /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 12M
innodb_log_file_size = 50M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 300
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

Comment: How do you tell it's not working? Could you please post the query you are trying to run?

Comment: most (>50%) of those 433 queries should have cached.

I can run:
"select * from student limit 10;" repeatedly
and it will increment the Qcache_not_cached number, but won't cache the query.

Comment: Additionally, that query returns well less than the query_cache_limit of 1M

Comment: Ok, some additional information.  This seems to be related to Innodb. MyISAM queries seem to cache just fine.

Comment: very little transactions, 98% (ish) of the queries are single ones

Comment: I have exactly same problem on Debian Linux. Currently investigating its cause.

Answer (score 1):

Does you database name contain *a dot* or other non-alphanumeric characters?

Do you use `innodb_file_per_table`?

If so you'll need to rename your database by means of dumping and restoring with new name.